# A better alternative to Windows XP Event Viewer?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, event-log, event-viewer

Is there one available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly useful.

[Sysinternals Event Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx)

Comment: Now name as `PsLogList`

Answer (score 3):

[MyEventViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html)